# Error in library ("dtw") : there is no package called "dtw"

Tags: r, command-prompt

I am trying to run an R script from the Windows Command Prompt but is running into the following error:

> Error in library("dtw") : there is no package called 'dtw'
>   Execution halted

The code that I typed is just RScript ...R

The R script actually runs in RStudio, and the address returned from `.libPaths()` function contains the "dtw" package.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install dtw successfully? install.packages('dtw')

Comment: Yes, I already installed it and it's in the library folder.

Comment: did you also try the `require("dtw")`, don't think it gonna change something though, also please try to call other librarys like ggplot2 or anything.

Comment: otherwise i think the next step should be checking your environment and path variables to your library folder